# Is Arduino code portable to custom PCB?

Tags: c++, arduino, atmega

I'm working on a Mega 2560 board. I plan to move my project to a custom PCB using a bare ATmega2560 microcontroller (same as the one on Arduino). From what I have researched, there is no clear answer to my question.

Can I program the Arduino with the Arduino IDE and later port all this code to my own PCB? I see that the Arduino IDE creates .cpp files corresponding to all the sketches.

I understand that I would have to keep all referenced Arduino pins and peripherals from the Eagle schematics.

EDIT: As pointed out in the answers below, you can use Arduino code on your own PCB, provided you don't use any third party libraries. You can use the hex files the Arduino IDE generates to program the microcontroller on the PCB via Atmel Studio or using Arduino as ISP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible to flash Arduino code into your own creations. I have done this several times. However you need an ISP to flash the target.

Depending on the hardware of your PCB some libraries may not work or not deliver the desired results.

Everything that relies on exact timing requires a crystal oscillator. (However the newer Arduinos only have a resonator, thus this might not be an issue for you).

Everything that needs to run at 16 Mhz requires a crystall as the internal PLL only supports up to 8 Mhz.

Everything that requires serial IO must be compiled with matching frequencies.

--> Unless you know what you do it is recommended to have a 16 Mhz crystall oscilator.

The serial to USB converter is purely optional but if you ommit it you will not be able to use the IDE's serial monitor or the boot loader option.

In all cases you have to ensure that you set the fuses properly. If you flash a bootloader with the IDE the IDE will automatically set the fuses properly. Since you need an ISP anyway you might want to consider to remove the bootloader afterwards. But this is mostly a matter of personal preferences.

Comment: Could you possibly link me to a resource with more details? I tried to setup Atmel Studio to code directly in C++ but keep getting errors that don't even show up on Google.

Comment: Your question was about the Arduino IDE now you are asking about Atmel Studio. The primary resource for Atmel Studio is not Arduino but the Atmel documentation and datasheets. If you did not get them with Atmel studio you can download them from Atmel. Did you already read them? If so, please be more specific, which OS, which C compiler, which errors.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to ask anything about Atmel Studio. I just meant that I'd prefer to use the Arduino IDE and was wondering if there was more out there that I might have missed.

Comment: Depends on what you have already read. Would you please give more details?

Comment: I have mostly read through past senior design projects from my own school and others. While most of them mention using an AVR micro controller and the Arduino IDE, they don't go through the process of how they identified what components to keep when they migrated to their own PCBs.

Comment: I suggest to first learn to deal with an ISP. You can start by reflashing an Arduino board. That way you know that all mistakes are on your side. Once you are confident with this read the Atmel datasheet and roll your own. It is not that hard.

Comment: Referencing the 16MHz information. That is accurate. The Arduino team don't pass the reference to the F_CPU compiler variable, when compiling all their delays and timers. They hard code F_CPU as 16MHz or 8MHz and the only source of truth. Now although F_CPU is called appropriately in [Arduino.h](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/598ab1d5c003e02b6bb193640fac8526ad8ab912/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Arduino.h) and [Wiring.c](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/598ab1d5c003e02b6bb193640fac8526ad8ab912/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/wiring.c), it is still wrong for any other F_CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Keep several things such as used GPIO, crystal, EEPROM (if present) and maybe service LEDs on your PCB like they were done in arduino and everything will be working. 
But I recommend to move to your own libraries and some free ones. You'll be able to detach from Arduino platform and use other Atmel microcontollers (for bigger or smaller purposes).

Answer: It will work if you move some valuable hardware (GPIO, SPI, crystal oscillator) to your PCB.

Comment: GPIO and SPI are inside the controllers and is not part of the PCB. At most the connectors for the GPIO pins are required. Crystall oscillator is optional if exact timing is not required and 8 MHz are sufficient. See my answer above.

Comment: Udo, I meant that he have to clone Arduino schematics for MC interfaces he use, to ensure that they will work same way. And use same GPIO ports. A lot of valuable things, such crystal oscillator, pullups might not be so obvious in Arduino PCB, so check of Arduino schematics is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont use Arduino librairies and you stay on the same atmega model then the general code should work. You might have to adapt a couple of things tho depending on what your pcb has. The important is that you keep it on Atmega and you dont use Arduino's librairies. But it might be possible to export those? I'm not sure about that.